# How can I filter by 2 different properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am attempting to filter an array of objects before sending it to the backend. It should go to the backend with NO falsy values.

If I do this it works:

`theArray.filter(({ name }) => name)`

But I need to add one more property:

```
theArray.filter(({ name, percentage }) => { return { percentage, name } }),
```

if I do it like above, it doesn't work, what am I missing?

Comment: Hi @peinearydevelopment post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your filter function should return a boolean value that determines whether or not to keep the array element:

```
theArray.filter(({name, percentage}) => {return name && percentage});
```

or just

```
theArray.filter(({name, percentage}) => name && percentage);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take the values and use either [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()) (no [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values)

```
theArray.filter(({ name, percentage }) => name && percentage)
```

or [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) (one or both values are [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)).

```
theArray.filter(({ name, percentage }) => name || percentage)
```

Answer (score 1):

So, what you are doing currently is pulling the name property out of each object in the array and then doing a 'truthy' test on it.

For a string(presumably like name), that means `undefined`, `null` and empty string would equate to false.

For a number(presumably like percentage), that means `undefined`, `null` and `0` would equate to false.

That being the case you could could use the following(keeping the above caveats in mind):

`theArray.filter(({ name, percentage }) => percentage && name)`